# Windows Server 2012 using Remote Desktop through RRAS to private network

Tags: routing, hyper-v, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, rras

I've already posted this on the Microsoft TechNet forums, but his site seems to provide more informative answers, so here goes...

Here is my network configuration, in a nutshell.

- Cisco small business switch is connected to wireless router (10.77.79.0/24) which is connected to the Internet.
- Hyper-V host has two physical connections to the small business switch: one for management, and the other for the Hyper-V external virtual switch.
- within Hyper-V there is an internal virtual switch which is hosting my server VMs (192.168.1.0/24).
- there is a proxy server (a Hyper-V VM) which has two network interfaces, one connected to the external virtual switch (10.77.79.80; gateway points to wireless router) and the other connected to the internal virtual switch (192.168.1.1; no gateway).  This proxy server has the Windows Server 2012 R2 RRAS role installed and is configured for NAT only.  The internal VMs have a static IP address configured to point to the internal interface of the proxy server for both the gateway and primary DNS.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to configure RRAS on the proxy server to allow RDP connections from the wireless network.  I've been searching for a couple days now with most posts saying simply "it just works"...it doesn't for me.

There are no firewalls in-between any device (software firewalls or otherwise).  RDP works in-between the internal IP of the proxy server to/from the internal VMs, and vice-versa.  My end-game is to RDP into the internal VMs from any device on my wireless network, providing the correct NAT and forwarding rules are in-place.

I'm hoping I'm missing something simple, or maybe my desired configuration isn't possible...not sure.

Answer (score 1):

High level principe

If your wireless network is a network considered as "external network", allowing users to connect at your environment with RDP protocol, the network connected to the WIFI router must be configured as Proxy in RRAS console.

Furthermore, for access from Internet at your environment, you must activate the VPN/SSL on your gateway and publish your environment on a public DNS.

Also, configure a ip range (as DHCP service) for the VPN clients & Autorize TCP RDP protocol to them.